# How to compare day in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
export const fetchDailyData = async () => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}/daily`);

        let today = new Date('2020-01-27');
        let referanceDay = new Date(dailyData.reportDate)

        const modifiedData = data.map((dailyData) => ({

            if(referanceDay => today){
                confirmed: dailyData.confirmed.total,
                deaths: dailyData.deaths.total,
                date: dailyData.reportDate
            };
        }))

        // return modifiedData

    } catch (error) {

    }
}
```

I am trying to compare days and return proper ones. But it's not worked. I think I got a mistake  object and if section. Could you please look my problem. Thanks..

Comment: `referanceDay => today` is not valid, try `referenceDay >= today` (See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

Daily data is argument to anon. Function but being referenced out in which case it would be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your >= comparison in your if statement is backwards. Also you are referencing dailyData before it is declared inside mapTry this:

```
export const fetchDailyData = async () => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}/daily`);

        let today = new Date('2020-01-27');

        const modifiedData = data.map((dailyData) => ({
            let referanceDay = new Date(dailyData.reportDate)
            if(referanceDay >= today){
                confirmed: dailyData.confirmed.total,
                deaths: dailyData.deaths.total,
                date: dailyData.reportDate
            };
        }))

        // return modifiedData

    } catch (error) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a library to compare the dates. I use Moment.js for all my datetime operations.

[enter link description here](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

example from docs :

```
moment('2010-10-20').isAfter('2010-01-01', 'year'); // false
```